# unicode datagridview win forms

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, datagrid

I have problem with data grid view in win forms. If I try to display **'** character data grid view displays some weird characters. (â€˜ & â€™)

Anyone knows how to solve this problem to make it display '

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's an encoding issue.

Where does the data come from and how do you load it into the data grid view?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the UTF-8 byte sequence with the individual bytes displayed in the Windows-1252 encoding.

More specifically, the unicode codepoints 2018 and 2019 are the left and right single quotation marks respectively.  Their UTF-8 representations are E28098 and E28099.  In the Windows-1252 encoding the byte E2 is displayed as your accented *a* character,80 by the Euro symbol, and 98 / 99 displayed by corresponding final characters in your example.

Comment: ok, That *explains* the problem .  Any idea about the solution?