# Display German characters in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am reading a text file (in CSV format) which contains german characters. I am reading the content and adding it to DataGrid. After this, I am displaying DataGrid in DataGridView control.

My problem is that the german characters are not displayed properly in DataGridView.

To read file contents, I use the below code

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtDRGFileName.Text, Encoding.UTF8);
```

I ran in debug mode and the confirm that the german characters are being read correctly into string variable and also added correctly to DataRow

My issue is similar to [unicode datagridview win forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552414/unicode-datagridview-win-forms) . But I didn't find an answer for it.

Does anyone have a solution for it?

Comment: There's little point in forcing us to guess what it looks like.  Shooting off the hip, Encoding.UTF8 is probably wrong.  Encoding.Default would be the next guess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtDRGFileName.Text, Encoding.Default);
```

This works. Thanks to Hans Passant for the solution.